# Match Multiple Patterns in a String and Return Matches as Hash

Tags: ruby, regex, hash

I'm working with some log files, trying to extract pieces of data.

Here's an example of a file which, for the purposes of testing, I'm loading into a variable named `sample`. **NOTE:** The column layout of the log files is not guaranteed to be consistent from one file to the next.

```
sample = "test script result
Load for five secs: 70%/50%; one minute: 53%; five minutes: 49%
Time source is NTP, 23:25:12.829 UTC Wed Jun 11 2014
                                                          D
MAC Address    IP Address     MAC           RxPwr  Timing I
                              State         (dBmv) Offset P
0000.955c.5a50 192.168.0.1    online(pt)    0.00   5522   N
338c.4f90.2794 10.10.0.1      online(pt)    0.00   3661   N
990a.cb24.71dc 127.0.0.1      online(pt)    -0.50  4645   N
778c.4fc8.7307 192.168.1.1    online(pt)    0.00   3960   N
"
```

Right now, I'm just looking for IPv4 and MAC address; eventually the search will need to include more patterns. To accomplish this, I'm using two regular expressions and passing them to `Regexp.union`

```
patterns = Regexp.union(/(?<mac_address>\h{4}\.\h{4}\.\h{4})/, /(?<ip_address>\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})/)
```

*As you can see, I'm using named groups to identify the matches.*

The result I'm trying to achieve is a Hash. The key should equal the capture group name, and the value should equal what was matched by the regular expression.

Example:

```
{"mac_address"=>"0000.955c.5a50", "ip_address"=>"192.168.0.1"}
{"mac_address"=>"338c.4f90.2794", "ip_address"=>"10.10.0.1"}  
{"mac_address"=>"990a.cb24.71dc", "ip_address"=>"127.0.0.1"}  
{"mac_address"=>"778c.4fc8.7307", "ip_address"=>"192.168.1.1"}
```

Here's what I've come up with so far:

```
sample.split(/\r?\n/).each do |line|
  hashes = []
  line.split(/\s+/).each do |val|
    match = val.match(patterns)
    if match
      hashes << Hash[match.names.zip(match.captures)].delete_if { |k,v| v.nil? }
    end
  end
  results = hashes.reduce({}) { |r,h| h.each {|k,v| r[k] = v}; r }
  puts results if results.length > 0
end
```

I feel like there should be a more "elegant" way to do this. My chief concern, though, is performance.

Comment: IMO `awk` is very well suited for this job - unless this processing is part of some other larger program. Is `awk` acceptable?

Comment: Given data is not sufficient to tell how the table part should be identified from the rest (text).

Comment: @RaviH `awk` would be great, but you're correct, this is a part of a larger program. Thanks!